# Check if first word in string pleases condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-like

I am trying to filter [google-bots](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) from `user_agent` fields in my database. I am using `LIKE %text_I_want_to_check_%` and it works fine because so far all of the bot namings are unique, however, `AdsBot-Google` is not unique in a string, what differs from other `user_agents` is that `AdsBot-Google` is the first entry in a string.

Example of `user_agent` with google-bot:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G920A) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome Mobile Safari (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html)
```

Exmaple of `AdsBot-Google`:

```
AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)
```

As you can see both examples contains `AdsBot-Google`, the only difference is that the second one has it in the first word of a string.

My desired output:
SQL CASE which checks if `AdsBot-Google` is the first text in a string and does not interfere with other cases of `AdsBot-Google` being in a middle of a string. Something like this:

```
CASE
WHEN (sessions.user_agent like AdsBot-Google) then 'AdsBot-Google-Mobile-iPhone'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL `LIKE` operator in fact can check for something beginning a string:

```
SELECT *
FROM sessions
WHERE user_agent LIKE 'AdsBot-Google%';
```

Note that this would only match records where the user agent field begins with `AdsBot-Google`; it would not match `AdsBot-Google` occurring anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you, figured it right after then simply removing the `%` at the beginning would solve it for me!

Comment: Another quick check-up, having `%` in front pleases both conditions, when the word is the first one and when it's in the middle of a string, right?

Comment: @Jonas Yes, but keep in mind that there is always the chance that you might be matching the term as a substring of some other word.  To really nail down your corner cases here you should regular expressions, if your version of SQL would support it.